# Speeding up a simple UPDATE query on a huge table

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization, query-optimization

Here's my table:

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| CLID     | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| calldate | datetime     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| src      | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| dst      | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| billsec  | varchar(10)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| duration | time         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| debt     | float        | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| region   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| uniqueid | varchar(20)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

It has over 490,328 records. I have to update every single record in this table. Here's the query (I'm using mysqli in PHP):

```
UPDATE `All` 
SET `debt` = '$debt', `region` = '$region' 
WHERE `uniqueid` = $uid;
```

Unfortunately executing a single query takes ~1.4519529342651 seconds. Is there any way to speed it up?

Comment: Did you have index for `uniqueid` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza it's a primary key which is a type of an index right?

Comment: You could partition the table by uniqueid ranges, so the query would not have to look scan all rows. Also, you could try to update all those records in one go where dbt and region changes to the same values instead of updating each record individually.

Comment: Sorry miss that. If you have to update every single record probably  is easy if you create the table again `CREATE TABLE 'All' AS Select * FROM  WhereYouHaveTheData`.

Comment: Other option disable any index on `debt` or `region` during the update process. Because after each update the index will be rebuild. Then enable again at the end.

Comment: is that table MyISAM or InnoDB? could you provide full `CREATE TABLE` statement please? Does it take same time if execute directly on phpMyAdmin? show us your php code fragment.

Comment: What does `$uid` look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.45 seconds to update a single record is very bad performance, and highly unexpected.  Your query is intending to update a single row using a primary key.  You shouldn't notice the amount of time.

However, the engine cannot use the primary key index for this query, because of the way the condition is expressed.  Let's look at the query in more detail:

```
UPDATE `All` 
SET `debt` = '$debt', `region` = '$region' 
WHERE `uniqueid` = $uid;
-------------------^
```

Unless `$uid` has quotes *included* in the value, then it is being treated as something other than a string.  So, if you are passing in "1", then you have an integer compared to a string.  And this can prevent the use of indexes.  Oops.

My first suggestion is to fix your query by using parameters.  Barring that, put single quotes in:

```
UPDATE `All` 
SET `debt` = '$debt', `region` = '$region' 
WHERE `uniqueid` = ''$uid'';
```

If `uniqueid` actually looks like a number, consider storing it as a number rather than a string.

Of course, other things could be going wrong, such as:

- Other queries could be locking the table.
- You could be testing the query from a cold-start, and all subsequent queries will be blazing fast.
- The table could have triggers that are painfully slow.

Comment: @user3125731 . . . How long does it take now?

Comment: Currently it takes around 0.00058412551879883 seconds, which is good enough. That is, after modifying the query as you suggested and dropping the indexes from `CLID`, `calldate` and `debt` columns.

Comment: @user3125731 . . . It sounds more dramatic to say 99.96% speed improvement ;)

Comment: Mine was an integer value, removed the quotes and the improvement is unbelievable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Before doing what I suggest I would definitely give Gordon Linoff's solution a try as it makes a lot of sense (missing quotes around the value passed on the where clause).

Is your MySQL database is distant from your PHP server? That could explain poor performances.

If you are having better performances when doing it directly on the phpMyAdmin interface, I would try passing multiple updates at the same time (see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.multiple-statement.php).

Like that (this is not actual code, it's just to give you an idea of what I mean here):

```
$i = 0;
$query = '';

while (yourcondition){

  if ($i < 50){
    // Change values of your $dbt, $region and $uid varialbes here and concatenate the new statement to the existing $query var
    $query .='UPDATE `All` 
      SET `debt` = '$debt', `region` = '$region' 
      WHERE `uniqueid` = $uid; '
  } else {
    // Execute your update on your mysqli object then empty your $query and set $i to 0
    $mysqli->query($query);
    $query = '';
    $i = 0;
  }

  $i++;
}
```

Start with 50 and see if it improves the performances, if it does, increase it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add indexes to particular update columns in mysql, and put array containing those ids while programming. 
At the end update single command with ids IN in it.

Hope above is clear!